# Spring.NET with MVC3 (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, spring.net

I'm experimenting with *ASP.NET MVC3 Razor* and I'm fairly impressed. This is the way we'll go.

We use *Spring.NET* for dependency injection in our framework and I wonder, if it is possible to use it for *MVC3* projects as well?

The documentation of *Spring.NET* is only talking about *MVC2*, but I guess there will be *MVC3* support in future release. Nonetheless I was trying to get it work though. With no success so far.

So my question is, if someone else found a way or workaround or trick to do dependency injection in *MVC3* using *Spring.NET* and if so, how?

I know this is a very general question, but even a honest "sorry this is definitely not possible" or "it should work without any modifications" would help me a lot.

Thanks in advance,
Jan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, even though the the latest Spring.NET release (1.3.1) has explicit support for MVC2, it can also be (pretty easily) used to support MVC3.  The IDependencyResolver interface introduced with MVC3 makes IoC integration significantly more straightforward than it had been in the past (offering just one single interception/pluggability point for type resolution where previously there had been multiple places you needed to intercept type resolution calls).

See blog posts like this one: http://blog.alexkyprianou.com/2011/03/07/using-spring-net-with-mvc-3/ for more information and suggestions on how you might go about doing this (its really quite simple compared to the effort/complexity of doing so with MVC1 and MVC2.

Comment: Yes, I've read this blog entry earlier, when I searched the web for a solution and tried it out. It didn't help with my original problem, which later turned out to be a formatting error. Thanks for the very useful answer!

Answer (score 2):

**It should work without modifications.**

After some more investigation and help of colleages I found out, that Spring.NET works with MVC3 - at least as far as I can see it now. My orignal problem was a misformatted xml-file for my injection objects (I didn't post the code in the question).

Still there seem to be issues with object scopes. The scope `request` doesn't seem to work, since all my objects are still singletons and once created, can not handle more than one request.

I tried to add the well-known attribute `singleton="false"` and it worked somehow, so my objects will now be created on every request. Good!

However I found out, that *Spring.NET*'s example `Spring.MvcQuickStart.2010` also uses the `singleton` attribute with value `false`, so probably this is the correct way (and `true` by default).

I don't know yet, how to handle the `session` scope, but at least my web application works for requests (`singleton="false"`) and application-wide (no `singleton` attribute) with Spring.NET and MVC3.

Best,
Jan

Comment: The session scope problem was actually a bug in Spring.NET which is described and worked around here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060386/spring-net-and-mvc3-on-iis7-session-scope-behaviour