# Spring.NET and MVC3 on IIS7 - session scope behaviour

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, scope, spring.net

probably it's a stupid question and I simply did not understand how Spring and IIS work, but lets give it a try.

I'm quite new to ASP.NET and as far as I understand, the session handling is similar to Apache/PHP:

*A session is shared between tabs of a browser, but not between different browsers. I.e. if I open my page in Firefox and put something in the cart, the cart will still contain my items in another tab, but opening the very same page in Internet Explorer should show me an empty cart.*

However I cannot reproduce this behaviour using Spring.NET.

I made a hello-world with a shopping cart object which is noted in session scope:

```
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
  <object id="shoppingCart" type="DemoShop.Models.Cart.ShoppingCart, DemoShop" singleton="true" scope="session" />
</objects>
```

If I add something into my cart, it persists across any tab and browser. So this looks to me as if this object is a real singleton and thus persistent during the runtime of the IIS application.

I know, what you are going to say: Why did I use the attribute `singleton="true"` in my spring config? Well if I remove it or set it to `false`, then the object will not persist in the session, but will be re-created on every request and thus lose it's data.

The Spring.NET documentation is not speaking about the `singleton` attribute in MVC context at all and it took me some time to figure out, that it seem to be required using MVC3.

I was able to successfully create application scope objects using

```
<object id="..." type="..., ..." singleton="true" scope="application" />
```

and request scope object using either

```
<object id="..." type="..., ..." scope="request" />
```

or

```
<object id="..." type="..., ..." singleton="false" scope="request" />
```

However leaving the `singleton` attribute out, always put my object in request scope no matter which scope I actually noted in the `scope` attribute.

My guess is, that the session is not actually shared between Firefox and IE, but the cart object is simply in application scope, because I'm using spring the wrong way.

Can anyone give me advice or hints what I'm doing wrong or is this a problem in IIS7?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem? According to [the docs on webscopes](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web-mvc.html#web-mvc-objectscope) in asp.net mvc with spring.net, it should definitely be `<object id="myObject" type="MyType, MyAssembly" scope="session"/>`. Could it be that you have disabled session state using `<sessionState mode="Off" />
`?

Comment: Well, I've read the docs and I totally agree to you. Still, the instanciated object is always in request scope, whenever I leave out the `singleton` attribute. I can't even get an application scope object if I'm not setting `singleton` to `true` explicitly, no matter what my `scope` attribute says. Tht is what makes me so curious. However I didn't solve it yet. I will create a simple MVC2 hello world app to check, if it behaves as the docs say. I will also check my sessionState mode. And I'll post any progress here of course. Thank you!

Comment: I implemented Spring.NET into the default MVC2 app from ASP.NET and reproduced the very same behaviour: `scope` attribute gets ignored and `singleton` attribute creates either application scope objects or request scope objects. So the issue must be me. Will investigate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug.

After some excessive debugging of the spring.net source code we found out:

1. Support for session scoped objects is given by the `spring.web` dll
2. The `spring.web.mvc` dll does not depend on `spring.web`
3. This means, it is impossible to instantiate an `MvcApplicationContext` that can resolve session scoped objects

The following solution shows a custom `MvcApplicationContext` that fully enables session scoped objects within MVC3 using spring.net.

The reason why a standard application context cannot resolve web scopes is that it's using the class `RootObjectDefinition` whis doesn't know about the `scope` attribute (in the config xml). The `WebApplicationContext` instead instantiates `RootWebObjectDefinition` types, which know the scope.

The `WebObjectsFactory` overrides the method `CreateRootObjectDefinition` which returns instances of `RootWebObjectDefinition`. This is the one, we want to return from our application context. This is done by overriding the method `CreateObjectsFactory`.

Next thing, we have to override is the method `CreateXmlObjectDefinitionReader`. When spring is reading the metadata from the config, it will not parse additional attributes like `scope` if we don't take a specific reader. Therefore we will use the `WebObjectDefinitionReader` in our application context.

For the configuration of your session scoped objects, you can either leave out the `singleton` attribute or set it explicitly to `true`. Otherwise with value `false` the session scope will be disabled for sure.

EXAMPLE:

```
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
    <object id="shoppingCart" type="ShoppingCart, ..." singleton="true" scope="session" />
</objects>
```

Step-by-Step solution:

1. Create `MvcWebApplicationContext` inheriting from `MvcApplicationContext`. You will need to override the two methods mentioned above and create default constructors.
2. Create a `MvcWebContextHandler` inheriting from `MvcContextHandler`. This will trigger that our custom application context will be used.
3. Use custom context handler in your `web.config`.
4. For IIS6 support or visual studio build-in webserver: add `WebSupportModule` to `system.web` section.
5. For IIS7 support: Add `WebSupportModule` to `system.webserver` section.

web.config:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
        <section name="context" type="YourNamspace.MvcWebContextHandler, YourAssembly"/>    
        ....
    </sectionGroup>    
    ....
</configSections>

<!-- IIS6 -->
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>

<!-- IIS7 -->
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
        <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Custom application context class:

```
public class MvcWebApplicationContext: MvcApplicationContext {

    public MvcWebApplicationContext(string name, bool caseSensitive, params string[] configurationLocations)
    : this(new MvcApplicationContextArgs(name, null, configurationLocations, null, caseSensitive))
    { }

    public MvcWebApplicationContext(string name, bool caseSensitive, IApplicationContext parentContext, params string[] configurationLocations)
    : this(new MvcApplicationContextArgs(name, parentContext, configurationLocations, null, caseSensitive))
    { }

    public MvcWebApplicationContext(MvcApplicationContextArgs args)
    : base(args)
    { }

    public MvcWebApplicationContext(string name, bool caseSensitive, string[] configurationLocations, IResource[] configurationResources)
    : this(new MvcApplicationContextArgs(name, null, configurationLocations, configurationResources, caseSensitive))
    { }

    public MvcWebApplicationContext(params string[] configurationLocations)
    : this(new MvcApplicationContextArgs(string.Empty, null, configurationLocations, null, false))
    { }

    protected override XmlObjectDefinitionReader CreateXmlObjectDefinitionReader(DefaultListableObjectFactory objectFactory)
    {
        return new WebObjectDefinitionReader(GetContextPathWithTrailingSlash(), objectFactory, new XmlUrlResolver());
    }

    protected override DefaultListableObjectFactory CreateObjectFactory()
    {
        return new WebObjectFactory(GetContextPathWithTrailingSlash(), IsCaseSensitive);
    }

    private string GetContextPathWithTrailingSlash()
    {
        string contextPath = this.Name;
        if (contextPath == DefaultRootContextName)
        {
            contextPath = "/";
        }
        else 
        {
            contextPath = contextPath + "/";
        }
        return contextPath;
    }
}
```

Custom context handler class:

```
public class MvcWebContextHandler : MvcContextHandler {

    protected override Type DefaultApplicationContextType
    {
        get { return typeof(MvcWebApplicationContext); }
    }  
}
```

We added this bug to Spring.NET's issue tracker:
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPRNET-1450

Comment: This is the bug on Spring.net's issuetracker: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPRNET-1450

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to post that. I added the jira link to the answer post. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Nice post; good to see you found a fix/workaround. On the Spring issue tracker I read that this bug was confirmed and that it was fixed in spring.net 1.3.2 for asp.net mvc 3. No fix yet for 1.3.1 / asp.net mvc 2 however.

Comment: Indeed. But as you can see, the workaround is very simple. Just override two methods in two classes and you are done. Can also be done directly in the spring.net source code and re-compiled.